# почему когда задаю имя свойства выдает ошибку?

Tags: javascript

```
var points = [
  "Aleks", 0,
  "Irina", 60,
  "Gleb", 30,
  "Anton", 30,
  "Victoria", 30,
  "Valera", 100
];


var students = [];
for (var i = 0; i < points.lentgh; i+2)
  students.push({ points[i] : points[i+1] });
console.log(students);
```

Comment: а какую ошибку выдает мы должны видимо сами догадаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала у вас в самом цикле опечатка в `length` и `i+2` вместо `i+=2`. Динамические ключи заключайте в квадратные скобки.

```js
var points = [
  "Aleks", 0,
  "Irina", 60,
  "Gleb", 30,
  "Anton", 30,
  "Victoria", 30,
  "Valera", 100
];

var students = [];
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i+=2){

  students.push({ [points[i]] : points[i+1] });
}
console.log(students);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var points = [
  "Aleks", 0,
  "Irina", 60,
  "Gleb", 30,
  "Anton", 30,
  "Victoria", 30,
  "Valera", 100
];


var students = [];
for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i = i+2) {
  var newObj = {};
  newObj[points[i]] = points[i + 1];
  students.push(newObj);
}
console.log(students);
```